# Использование foreach с несколькими условиями

Tags: php, foreach

Есть массив:

```
`$array = [ 
   'title' => ['Iphone', 'Samsung', 'Xaomi', 'Oppo', 'Nokia'],
   'path' => ['root/iphone/index.php', 
              'root/samsung/index.php', 
              'root/xaomi/index.php', 
              'root/oppo/index.php', 
              'root/nokia/index.php']
];`
```

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы внедрить его в ссылку:

```
<a href = 'путь до папки'>'Название'</a> 
<a href = 'root/iphone/index.php'>Iphone</a>
```

Далее по аналогии понятно, что нужен `foreach`, но как его корректно использовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($array['title'] as $key=>$title){
echo '<a href="'.$array['path'][$key].'">'.$title.'</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [ 
   'title' => ['Iphone', 'Samsung', 'Xaomi', 'Oppo', 'Nokia'],
   'path'  => ['root/iphone/index.php', 'root/samsung/index.php', 'root/xaomi/index.php', 'root/oppo/index.php', 'root/nokia/index.php']
];

foreach($array['title'] as $key => $value){
    echo '<a href = "' . $array['path'][$key] . '">' . $value . '</a> ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [
    'title' => [
        'Iphone', 
        'Samsung',
        'Xiaomi',
        'Oppo',
        'Nokia',
    ],
    'path'  => [
        'root/iphone/index.php',
        'root/samsung/index.php',
        'root/xaomi/index.php',
        'root/oppo/index.php',
        'root/nokia/index.php',
    ],
];

foreach (array_combine($array['title'], $array['path']) as $title => $path) {
    echo "<a href=\"{$path}\">{$title}</a>";
}
```

Ребята, учите PHP!!! Не забивайте на кодстайл! PSR никто не отменял!
https://repl.it/@Piterden/PHP-SHIT